# REST URL convention

Tags: api, rest, http

I have an application table that has columns like quoteId, accountNumber, and few others. I have created a REST endpoint to update the account number on the basis of quoteId i.e Update account no. in the application that has quoteId = {quoteId}. Here is the endpoint:

```
PUT /applications/quotes/{quoteId}/accountNumber
```

Is it the correct REST convention?

Comment: The characters that form a URI is not of relevance in a REST architecture. As such suggestions on how one should look like represent primarily opinions rather than facts. REST is probably also something different than you think. I.e. REST just utilizes well defined media-types payloads are exchanged for to increase interoperability and rely on an interaction model that is similar to the one used on the Web where servers teach clients on the available options and how to form requests (i.e. through forms). As such REST has no endpoints but resources and also does not expose the DB model directly

Answer (score 1):

> Is it the correct REST convention?

Maybe.

If your PUT/PATCH/POST request uses the same URI as your GET request, then you are probably on safe ground.  If PUT/PATCH/POST are using different URI, then something has Gone Wrong somewhere.

In other words, if `/applications/quotes/{quoteId}/accountNumber` is a resource that you *link* to, then it is the right idea that you send unsafe requests to that URI.

But if accountNumber is information normally retrieved via `/applications/quotes/{quoteId}`, then `/applications/quotes/{quoteId}` should be the target resource for edits (instead of creating a new resource used for editing only).

The reason for this is [cache-invalidation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234#section-4.4), as explained in RFC 7234.

If this isn't immediately clear to you, then I suggest reviewing [Jim Webber's 2011 talk on REST](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=188s).

Answer (score 0):

You should use PATCH instead of PUT for partial object updates.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PATCH

https://www.infoworld.com/article/3206264/how-to-perform-partial-updates-to-rest-web-api-resources.html

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your url must be:

`PUT /applications/quotes/{quoteId}`

```
payload: {
   accountNumber: <number>,
   ... any other field...
}
```

Because you only want to update a part of an object of the list of `quotes` that you identify uniquely with `quoteId`.

About the use of `PUT` or `PATCH`, it's true that `PUT` means that you want to keep the object as the updated copy that you are sending (you must send in this case the entire object to make the update) but the fact is (I think) that many of us use `PUT` like you, to do partial updates of object.